# mysql query back end sort result

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sorting

I have table `tbl`:

```
name state
x a
x d
x c
y b
y a
```

Right now I get this from my query:

```
x a
x c
x d
y a
y b
```

but I need to back only this:

```
x d
y b
```

Comment: What are you talking about?  Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple `group by` and `max`

```
select name,
    max(state) state
from tbl
group by name;
```

Comment: what if i dont write group by name

Comment: whow this group data and back result